# How can we automatically trigger the protractor script at specific time intervals

Tags: javascript, protractor

I am entering data from the DB to our application through protractor script.So now i am running the protractor script by the command 'protractor conf.js' from the command prompt.But i have to trigger the protractor script automatically instead of doing it manually from the command prompt.Do we have any methods or code for automatically trigger the protractor script in every specific time interval. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Try this package: https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-schedule

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simplest way is to create a batch file with two commands and schedule a task with Operating systems Task scheduler.

1. To cd to the project directory
2. Trigger Protractor test

Example:

```
cd C:\Coding_Core\Protractor_tests

protractor conf.js
```

You should create a task with task scheduler and in trigger section specify the time and intervals

[image: Task Scheduler]

Comment: Hi Bharath,can we execute this batch file according to a condition.I need to execute a sql query and depends on the data from DB(1 or null),then only i need to start the protractor script(if it is null then i need to execute the protractor script).So How can i do this?

Comment: You can use nodejs chid process for this.On a condition you can run a bat file.

Comment: Ok...IF i am having a service in c#, and giving the sql query execution in that.So can i take the query response in the service itself and say execute the batch file by giving its path.Means executing the batch file according to the response from a service.

Comment: You can do that.